# how to Create web services | asp.net 2.0 | C# | web services

Tags: web-services, c#-2.0, asp.net-2.0

Below is my requirement ...please guide me to do well...

ServiceName: Login

Invoke URL:

http://mysite.com/api/loginuser.asp?mechineid=2We3fght5#&username=sankar@gmail.com&password=welcome

XML return format:

PS: i need to return in XML format....

How to create webservices explain me in detail....

ragards,

shankar.M

Comment: How to create web services: [**in detail**](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=web+services&x=0&y=0)

Comment: I wish I was kidding. You are asking a community of developers to delve into detail about one of the broadest and most complex topics in the industry. There are thousands of resources out there that can tell you how to go about implementing a web service. This forum is for helping developers figure out problems after they have tried to solve it themselves, not a place to get free code dumps.

Comment: 1. Please don't stuff tags into your post title, use the *tags* field; 2. Please [don't use signatures or taglines in your posts](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures); 3. Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and, in the future, try to ask *specific* questions about programming rather than broad "write this for me" style questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
[WebMethod]
public string HelloWorld()
{
    return "Hello World";
}

in web.config...

Answer (score 0):

How about some of these:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228289%28v=vs.80%29.aspx
- http://www.15seconds.com/issue/010430.htm
- http://www.developerfusion.com/article/3114/building-xml-web-services-using-c-and-aspnet/
- http://blogs.sitepoint.com/net-web-services-5-steps/